# How to Iterate across a web table utilizing Selenium IDE Version 3.13.0

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to automate regression tests using the new selenium ide version 3.13. I wanted to get dynamic values and not hard code my values. I have a table which i want to loop through and then click on the element. I been trying everything but nothing works all i see is examples from the old selenium ide when "store eval" was a command. please can you run me step by step on how to achieve this with the new selenium ide.

I have tried the following:
1. get the element that highlights all the rows i want to click on 
2. now i just need to know how to iterate it one element at a time within the table going down. click verify text and move on to the next one click verify text.

My xpath:xpath=/html/body/div[4]/tracer-app/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/ng-component/form/div/div[2]/div/questions-library/div/div[2]/div[1]/div

```
            </a>
            <!--template bindings={}--><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Accreditation Participation Requirements Question Library
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Behavioral Health Care Inpatient
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item lib-selected">
                Cardiac and Pulmonary Rehabilitation
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Central Venous Catheter Audit
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Chemotherapy Administration
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                CLABSI Prevention
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Clinical Alarm Safety
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Clinical Alarm Safety - Telemetry
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Complaint and Grievance - Deemed Status
            </a><a _ngcontent-csk-87="" class="list-group-item">
                Contracted Services
```

Expected results: click on each template, verify text and move on to the next element verify text in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my code:[image]
I've used [while](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#while) command to make a loop with `i` as iterator.

To switch between links I've put `i` iterator inside xpath - `//div[@class='main-navbar']/div/ul/li[${i}]/a` (6 row on the pic)

I have `exepexted_values` array that contains tab names that I expect to find on the page. So in the 12th row I check tab name with the value from this array. Then I increase my iterator and start all over again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but i tried and no luck .... i really need this

Comment: 1. Get the maximum child element count (151) 2. get the minimum child element count (1) - while loop - $(min)<$(max) and then clicked the xpath and changed the number of links 1-151  to {$min} and i would click and and then verify text and then  i would  put in the execute script - return Number (${min})+1  but this isnt working it keeps on clicking on just the 1st link

Comment: Hi! You should check element xpath you want to click. Variable ${min} should be used in it to switch between child elements. Try to use ChroPath extension to write and check xpaths. I usually do mistakes in iterator increasing command, check that it is correct(`execute script|return Number (${min})+1|min`)

Comment: Hi Maria, yes i do have the correct xpath and changed the last div with the the link i want to click on. I tried your statement return Number (${min})+1|min) but still nto working displaying "unexpected token". I am seeing everything is working except for the increment it keeps looping the same link.